# How to store mutiple comments with 3 fields in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
 foreach ($big_response as $data) {
     $comment_data[comment][name] = $data->name;
     $comment_data[comment][date] = $data->createdAt;
     $comment_data[comment][message] = $data->message;
 }
```

The above just prints out a comment array just once but not for all the values in $big_response.

```
 array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } ["comment"]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> NULL ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-01-07T08:56:23" ["message"]=> string(45) "HELLO WORLD" } }
```

I'm trying to print an array structured as following:

```
    Array
    (
    [comment] => Array
      (
      [name] => Tom
      [date] => 12/12/12
      [message] => Hello World
      )
    [comment] => Array
      (
      [name] => Andy
      [date] => 12/12/14
      [message] => Hello World2
      )
    [comment] => Array
      (
      [name] => Peter
      [date] => 12/12/13
      [message] => Hello World3
      )
    )
```

All values are string types. Actually I want to store the resulting array in a json file after json_encode(ing) it.

Where am I lacking at? Let me know If i can provide more details.

Comment: You are replacing your array elements with each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this is you are basically just overwriting `$comment_data[comment]…` with each loop:

```
foreach ($big_response as $data) {
  $comment_data[comment][name] = $data->name;
  $comment_data[comment][date] = $data->createdAt;
  $comment_data[comment][message] = $data->message;
}
```

And this array result will never happen since you can have multiple keys with the same key value of `comment`:

```
Array
(
[comment] => Array
  (
  [name] => Tom
  [date] => 12/12/12
  [message] => Hello World
  )
[comment] => Array
  (
  [name] => Andy
  [date] => 12/12/14
  [message] => Hello World2
  )
[comment] => Array
  (
  [name] => Peter
  [date] => 12/12/13
  [message] => Hello World3
  )
)
```

Try this instead using a `key` value from the `$big_response` array when doing the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($big_response as $data_key => $data_value) {
  $comment_data[$data_key][comment][name] = $data->name;
  $comment_data[$data_key][comment][date] = $data->createdAt;
  $comment_data[$data_key][comment][message] = $data->message;
}
```

The output of this would be something like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [comment] => Array (
      [name] => Tom
      [date] => 12/12/12
      [message] => Hello World
    )
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [comment] => Array (
      [name] => Andy
      [date] => 12/12/14
      [message] => Hello World2
    )
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [comment] => Array (
      [name] => Peter
      [date] => 12/12/13
      [message] => Hello World3
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, using the key worked out for me. Just for learning purpose, if you could direct me to a resource where I can learn more about the problem and create complex array structures myself, it would be great.

Comment: Correct! I'm dumb. by the way, I knew it that arrays have unique key for a value but still shit happens.

Answer (score 2):

Add a Counter:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($big_response as $data) {
   $comment_data[comment][$i][name] = $data->name;
   $comment_data[comment][$i][date] = $data->createdAt;
   $comment_data[comment][$i][message] = $data->message;
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Are there pros of using a counter instead of a key from big_response like Jake suggested? Any performance gain? I'm curious because you got more votes.

Comment: No, do as you like and try to find a Style where you stay on to make your Code more solid and less chaotic. Then you will find out what makes more sense in your individual Situation. But that takes a while and the more experience you get the more solid your Code will be.